# Capacitor NP in schematics

Tags: capacitor, schematics

What type of capacitor is the one shown in the schematics as NP?

[image]

Comment: a not populated polarised capacitor

Comment: Agreed, an unpopulated polarized cap

Comment: it's Not a Polymer Cap but more often it is a DNP part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NP means **Not Populated**: a component not to be mounted in that specific version of a board.

Sometimes the designer leaves a couple of NP components to accommodate for different versions of the same board or future expansions

Answer (score 2):

It's a capacitor, but it is Not Populated during manufacture.

It means, there is a place for capacitor, but it's left out.

Comment: What is the meaning of that?

Comment: That it is not physically put onto the PCB but the pads exist. Typically done to provision for

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for making it more clear.

Comment: Some years ago (20, 30?) at my company, in an attempt to save costs, a lot of the high speed decoupling caps were specified as NP, with the thought being that they could be added if problems showed up.  That idea died after a torturous history when they (management) realized the cost savings were not worth the aggravation (engineers at $100/hour) chasing down problems..